# probability that the root of a quadratic equation is real

Tags: probability, integration

Given joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{e^{\frac{-y}{2}}}{2}, y>0, 0<x<1\\
 0 , \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

We have a quadratic equation $a^2+2Xa+Y=0$, the question is what is the probability that the root of the quadratic equation is real.

I solved the quadratic equation and concluded that the answer is $P(X^2\geq Y)=$$1-\int_0^1 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$.  I tried hard but I don't know how to solve for the integral. Can you show a step by step solution?

Comment: The integral is expressed in terms of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: What are the marginal distributions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$?